# SpaceX launch site - why all the cables are needed around top of the rocket

Tags: spacex, launch-site, falcon-9, launchpad

On the SpaceX launch site (slc-40 launch pad) there are lot of cables suspended around top of the rocket (between four white rods). What is the function of them? Why no such cables is used on other launch sites?

Are cables damaged by starting rocket?

[image: Falcon 9 2014 april start - cables around top of the rocket]
[image: Falcon december 2013 launch, cables around rocket]

Comment: Contrary to your question, such cables are routinely used at other launch sites - here is a photo of the same style of lightning suppression setup around Ariane 5: http://www.arianespace.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2017/06/Arianespace_Spaceport_ELA-3_2x3/803201871.jpg